# browser.wait and conditions with Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

With protractor, I'm creating a customer object, and when saving I want to check that the customer object that just got created is actually displayed.

In "UI" term, after clicking on the save button there is a little delay where the dialog creation is closed and the customer list updated.

I have the original customerCount, so I want the browser to wait until there is customerCount + 1 customer card.

Here is my code :

Step :

```
When('I wait for the customer list to be updated', function() {
    return browser.wait(Utils.countElements('.tb-card-item', customerCount + 1), 5000);
});
```

countElements :

```
module.exports = {
    countElements(css, i) {
        let e = element.all(by.css(css));
        return e.count().then(function(elementCount) {
            console.log('COUNT : ' + elementCount);
            return elementCount === i;
        })
    }
};
```

My understanding was that the countElement function would be executed until it returns true, so until the number of customer is the right one. What happens in reality is that it gets executed once and goes straight to the next instruction, failing my tests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browser.wait` returns Promise object, according to [official](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) documentation.
Basically, there are two options how you can tell cucumber that this particular step is async.

First, if with `done` callback

```
When('I wait for the customer list to be updated', function(done) {
    browser.wait(Utils.countElements('.tb-card-item', customerCount + 1), 5000)
       .then(() => {
            done();
       })
})
```

Second, with `async` keyword

```
When('I wait for the customer list to be updated', async function() {
    await browser.wait(Utils.countElements('.tb-card-item', customerCount + 1), 5000);
});
```

But it is not enough just to return promise, like you did, cucumber has no idea how to deal with it. You have to tell cucumber that he can't move on, until this promise resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that because I was returning a promise it will wait for this promise to be successful before doing the next instruction, looks like I was wrong. Thanks again :)

Comment: Actually I tested again and none of the solution are working, it's going once into the countElements method and that's it, not over and over until it return true

Comment: @Bdloul The problem is not in the code I see, though, I'm not sure that `element` exists in that context. Try to pass an elements array instead of css selector